# t.references in Rails migration (n | n relationship)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, relationship, has-many, belongs-to

I have three models in my Rails 3 application, `DailyData` and `DailyDataVehicle` and `Vehicle`, a many to many relationship.

I just learned that if you update the model with the associations, that it doesn't update the database, so I am going back and adding those migrations.  I am also lucky enough to confidently think I know the differences between `belongs_to` and `has_many`, however, in my migration file, I am not sure that `t.references` does.
So I named the migration model `AddDailyDataToDailyDataVehicle`, and want to add the `dailyData_id` to the `daily_data_vehicles` table.  This is a many to many relationship, so I want the `id key` to be in the relationship table `DailyDataVehicles`, but I'm not quite sure that `t.references` will know that.
Maybe I am slightly mixing up the class associations and the database relationships, and if I am, then please clarify this.
If `t.references` is not what I want, do I have to declare the relationship manually with `has_many`, and if so, what is the syntax for that?

schema file currently:

```
create_table "daily_data_vehicles", :force => true do |t|
  t.integer  "vehicle_id"
  t.datetime "created_at", :null => false
  t.datetime "updated_at", :null => false
end
add_index "daily_data_vehicles", ["vehicle_id"], :name => "index_daily_data_vehicles_on_vehicle_id"
```

Migration (attempt):

```
class AddDailyDataToDailyDataVehicle < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    change_table :dailyDataVehicles do |t|
      t.references :dailyData
    end
    add_index :dailyDataVehicles, :dailyData_id
  end
end
```

What I think the schema file should look like if the migration works correctly:

```
create_table "daily_data_vehicles", :force => true do |t|
  t.integer  "vehicle_id"
  t.integer  "dailyData_id"
  t.datetime "created_at", :null => false
  t.datetime "updated_at", :null => false
end
add_index "daily_data_vehicles", ["vehicle_id"], :name => "index_daily_data_vehicles_on_vehicle_id"
add_index "daily_data_vehicles", ["dailyData_id"], :name => "index_daily_data_vehicles_on_daily_data_id"
```

with the difference being `t.integer  "dailyData_id"` and `add_index "daily_data_vehicles", ["dailyData_id"], :name => "index_daily_data_vehicles_on_daily_data_id"`

Comment: It would be like that only in your schema file

Comment: so t.references will solve the schema side? and then I have to adjust the models accordingly as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class AddDailyDataToDailyDataVehicle < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :daily_data_vehicles, : daily_data_id, :integer
    add_index :daily_data_vehicles, :daily_data_id
  end
end

class DailyDataVehicle < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :daily_data
end

class DailyData < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :daily_data_vehicles
end
```